# How do you count the number of vertices of a given class in an igraph object in R?

Tags: r, network-programming, igraph, bipartite

I'm working with a bipartite multilayer network in the igraph package for R.

Is there a way to count the number of vertices of a given class and the number of edges on a given layer?

The *summary* function gives me total counts and lists.

Here are the attributes of my network:

> IGRAPH 3e83b45 UNWB 501 1120 --
>   + attr: name (v/c), taxon (v/c), taxon.label (v/n), species.size (v/n), type (v/c), weight (e/n), type (e/c)
>   + edges from 3e83b45 (vertex names):

Vertex classes are coded as "taxon", layers (i.e., edge types) are coded as "type".

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd be nice if you provided a minimal reproducible example, but I think simply querying the vertices with `V()` and querying the edges with `E()` will get you what you want. They both provide a vector that you can use the `length()` function on

```
library(igraph)

g <- make_graph('zachary') %>%
  set_edge_attr(., 'type', value = sample(c('parent', 'child'),
                                          size = ecount(.), 
                                          replace = T)) %>%
  set_vertex_attr(., 'taxon', value = sample(c('species', 'family', 'class'), 
                                             size = vcount(.), 
                                             replace = T))

V(g)[taxon == 'species']
E(g)[type == 'parent']
```

Comment: Dear @struggles, thank you very much! That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I apologize for not providing a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: No worries, it's just a good habit to have. It's a 'help us help you' kind of thing.